# what is water line germ removal procedure

Tags: water

I have an old pipe line in my house. I need to clean the water paths inside the pipe. Is Filling chlorine in a dense quantity inside pipes a better way for germs removal ? how can we do that ? from where we get chlorine ? what is the procedure ? can you help.. ?

Comment: can you be more specific?  what do you mean by clean the water paths?  do you want to disinfect the pipes, or clean them to improve flow?  either way, it sounds like you need a plumber, as the municipality will have issues with you injecting anything into the lines that connect to the mains

Comment: Is this pipe connected to a cistern or tank, a water distribution system , a well...?

Answer (score 1):

Common 5.25% hypochlorite "liquid laundry bleach" (unscented) is the chlorine source that is typically used. It not used (and actually not even most effective) at full strength, but rather added to water in the system to achieve a certain concentration for a certain contact period.

Sources appear to vary between suggesting 10, 50 or 200 ppm chlorine concentration for a "shock treatment." Contact time suggestions range from 2-24 hours.

52.5 ppm would be 1 ml (5.25%) bleach per liter of water.

Do not exceed 200 ppm or 24 hours. More is not better beyond those, and there is debate regarding even going that high or for that long.

Flush the system throughly after disinfecting with chlorine bleach - there should be no remaining smell of chlorine.